Get list of private Dailymotion videos
I want to get list of private Dailymotion videos.
I am able to receive an access token with a private key. But then when I send Get request to retrieve the list of videos, I see the following "400 Bad Request: malformed Host header".
<?php
$url = "https://partner.api.dailymotion.com/oauth/v1/token";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array(
   "Host: partner.api.dailymotion.com",
   "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&scope=manage_videos";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$data = json_decode($resp, true);
$access_token = $data['access_token'];
$url = "https://partner.api.dailymotion.com/user/xxx/videos?fields=id&limit=30&private=true";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array(
    "Host: partner.api.dailymotion.com/rest",
);
$auth = "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token;
$headers[1] = $auth;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>


Don't set the Host header. You don't need to.

"Host: partner.api.dailymotion.com/rest" - that makes little sense; this isn't a host name.

The key used is actually Public API when the code is using Private API endpoint.
To access private data with public API key, access token will need to be generated with username and password along with the key and secret.
<?php
//Perform authentication
$url = "https://api.dailymotion.com/oauth/token";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array( 
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
$data = "grant_type=password&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&username=xxx&password=xxx&scope=email,feed,manage_analytics,manage_app_connections,manage_applications,manage_claim_rules,manage_domains,manage_features,manage_history,manage_likes,manage_player,manage_players,manage_playlists,manage_records,manage_subscriptions,manage_subtitles,manage_user_settings,manage_videos,read_insights,userinfo";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$data = json_decode($resp, true);

//Retrieve an access token
$access_token = $data['access_token'];

//Get the list of video IDs
$url = "https://api.dailymotion.com/user/xxx/videos?fields=private_id&private=true";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array(

);
$auth = "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token;
$headers[0] = $auth;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$data = json_decode($resp, true);
$ids = array_column($data['list'], 'private_id');
print_r($ids);
    ?>


You can try the following
$url = "https://api.dailymotion.com/user/xxx/videosfields=id&limit=30&private=true";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token,
    "Content-Type: application/json"
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


Please explain how this would solve the issue. What have you've actually changed to address the issue?

You're likely to get a more favourable response to your post if you take the time to explain your answer, including talking about what you've done and why you expect that it solves the problem. Just dumping code is actually not very helpful most of the time. See also [answer]. Thanks.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
